# How to groupby datetime periods by windows of time using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I'm creating a script to determine potential offenders on a process. I have the following data:

```
|  Name  | Issue Date  | Supplier  | Route       | Tickets  |
|  Jason |  1/1/2020   |  AA       |     EWR~SFO |  1       | 
|  Brad  |  1/5/2020   |  BA       |     EWR~LHR |  1       | 
|  Jason |  1/5/2020   |  AA       |     EWR~SFO |  1       | 
|  Nic   |  1/3/2020   |  DL       |     EWR~SFO |  1       | 
|  Jason |  1/11/2020  |  AA       |     EWR~SFO |  1       |
```

What I'm supposed to do, is to determine if there's a ticket on a window of 5 days with the same name, supplier and route. So for example, I want to get back this:

```
|  Name  |  Issue Date |  Supplier |  Route   |  Tickets |  Potential Offender |
|  Jason |  1/1/2020   |  AA       |  EWR~SFO |  1       |  Y                  | 
|  Brad  |  1/5/2020   |  BA       |  EWR~LHR |  1       |  N                  | 
|  Jason |  1/5/2020   |  AA       |  EWR~SFO |  1       |  Y                  | 
|  Nic   |  1/3/2020   |  DL       |  EWR~SFO |  1       |  N                  | 
|  Jason |  1/11/2020  |  AA       |  EWR~SFO |  1       |  N                  |
```

As you see, Jason issued a flight in the window of 5 days so he is a potential offender, however, he also issued another ticket with the same supplier and route but 6 days after his last issued ticket so he shouldn't be a potential offender for that...

I have tried to do this in numerous ways, so for example, I created a column that works like an Audit ID, just concatenated the Name/Supplier/Route and then used the following code:

```
df2 = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Issue Date", freq="5D"), "Audit ID"], as_index=False).sum()
```

My naive goal was that if the sum of tickets was >= 2, it meant that the Audit ID presented a potential offender, so then I'd just have to merge the two data frames together with the audit ID. But it doesn't work because my ID isn't unique because of the issue dates logic...

As a beginner using programming languages I don't know what can I do and I'm sure that there's a way of doing that like in R with the groupby and mutate function... so I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: There is a 7-day difference between rows 1 and 3, so why a "Y"?

Comment: My bad, I corrected the post! tks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` with `diff` and check if it is less than `'5 days'`:

```
df['Potential Offender'] = ((df.groupby(['Name', 'Supplier', 'Route'])
                                        ['Issue Date'].diff() < '5 days')
                               .replace([True,False], ['Y','N']))
df
Out[1]: 
    Name Issue Date Supplier    Route  Tickets Potential Offender
0  Jason 2020-01-01       AA  EWR~SFO        1                  N
1   Brad 2020-01-05       BA  EWR~LHR        1                  N
2  Jason 2020-01-05       AA  EWR~SFO        1                  Y
3    Nic 2020-01-03       DL  EWR~SFO        1                  N
4  Jason 2020-01-11       AA  EWR~SFO        1                  N
```